# How to use QA Service of IBM watson with REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, nlp-question-answering, retrieve-and-rank

I have just started to learn IBM Watson services. I need to use Question and answer API of bluemix in java using REST API. But I couldn't find any service like **Question and answer**. Please can anybody tell me is the name is changed or where can I find the documentation for this service. I have tried with existing answers in SO. But those links which are in answers are not working removed.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QA service has been discontinued since the end of last year.

Instead what has happened is that the components that made up QA have been broken down into their own services.

- [NL Classifier](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/nl-classifier.html)
- [Dialog](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/dialog.html)
- [Retrieve and Rank](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/retrieve-rank.html)
- [Document Conversion](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/document-conversion.html)

The reason for this change is that not all types of applications required all these services. Also it allows you to pull in other services to act on data, for example [Sentiment Analysis](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/alchemy-language.html) of a question can impact the answer/action given. Which wasn't part of QA.

More details here:

https://developer.ibm.com/watson/blog/2015/11/11/watson-question-and-answer-service-to-be-withdrawn/