# Watson Q/A Health to Dialog Service/Natural language classifier

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

I have been learning on building a simple application by replicating the Watson Health Q/A application(https://watsonhealthqa.mybluemix.net/) but the Q/A application seems to have been deprecated and documentation/forums seem to say that I should use the dialog service with the natural language classifier. Any pointers if this is the case. Second, where can I get the template file(dialog xml file with classifier), i.e for the dialog that is based on the already trained health data that  previously existed in the Q/A Health application. i.e would need to train the classifier with the same data they used for their Q/A application? Is this now under health services?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309764/how-to-use-qa-service-of-ibm-watson-with-rest-api/35310052#35310052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@simon's answer is correct and has links to the new services.  The older QA service has been deprecated and replaced by other, singularly focused services.  The new services are more flexible and more composable.

Side note... I guess I should update my demos (the URL you mention above) b/c those old services are no longer active.

Comment: Thank you very much, @andrew   I am curious, where can one get sample question training data. Started doing this but realized i need to build some training data. Any clue on sample training data for specific Q/A services i.e health as was in this example?